# Find the true and predicted labels in Tensorflow Federated

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-federated

I am having a multi-class classification problem and trying to evaluate the federated learning model by analyzing the True and Predicted values and producing the classification report.

But I am stuck with the y_true and y_pred, I don't know how to extract them for the federated computation.
The block of my federated model training:

```
  for round_num in range(0, NUM_ROUNDS):
    train_metrics = eval_process(state.model, test_data)['eval']
    state, _= iterative_process.next(state, train_data)

    print(f'Round {round_num:3d}: {train_metrics}')
    data_frame = data_frame.append({'Round': round_num,
                                      **train_metrics}, ignore_index=True)
  

  test_metrics = eval_process(state.model, test_data)
  print("The final evaluation is: ")
  print(test_metrics)

  return data_frame
```

The classification report I want to reach to:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

y_pred = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=64, verbose=1)
y_pred_bool = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_bool))
```

Any help will be so much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not an expert in `sklearn`, it looks like the classification report computes things like precision and recall. You could simply add those relevant metrics to your model (for example, through `tf.keras` if you're using a Keras model) and standard training/eval processes in TFF (eg. `tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation`) will compute them and aggregate them across clients.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I am using the `tf.keras` and I think you mean the standard evaluation metrics of keras like (`tf.keras.metrics.Precision` and `tf.keras.metrics.Recall`) which are -as I have read about it- built and used for binary classification. and I want to use it for Multi-class classification. I just tried them in my model and I am getting 0.0 for precision and recall. How can I adopt it to my model?

Comment: Most `tf.keras.metrics` are suitable for multi-class classification. This includes `tf.keras.metrics.Precision` and `tf.keras.metrics.Recall`. If you're seeing 0 for these values it suggests that the metrics are working, but your training isn't doing anything useful. I would try more rounds, and seeing if the loss is consistently decreasing.

Comment: That's right, it worked after some rounds. It is weird because I was reading about it for some time and all I see is saying that these metrics are not suitable for non-binary classification. Thanks.

Comment: Just a small question here! when using a `tf.keras.metrics.Recall` and `Precision`  for multi-class classification, does it use the average `macro` or `micro` by default? since it is not provided in the documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure what `macro` and `micro` refer to in this context. I'd recommend checking out the keras API docs on this.